# How exactly does priority bucket in android P will effect background job/task in my application?

Tags: android, performance

I have an application which downloads products list of store (*around 5000+ products*) at the start of application so as user can get product data in offline mode.

This is done through service in background in my application, now i need to support android P in my application, i figured out background task and FCM are affected by '**Priority Buckets**' introduced.

Products are spine of my app, and i want to avoid any unfortunate events. Right now my service is not a foreground service. I find it very difficult to create test environment for priority bucket role in app. I need to know what all should i keep in mind as i upgrade to P.

Comment: You can use Android IntentService to do the task.Or you can use jobIntentService

Comment: my service is already running on background thread, i am looking for affects of priority buckets with android P upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [blog](https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/exploring-android-p-priority-buckets-d34d12059d36):

An application will fall into one of five buckets:

> - **Active:** An application that is currently in use by the user. This
>     will be something that is in the foreground, has some system level
>     process running or being interacted with in some way. Note: If an
>     application does not have a launcher activity, then it may never be
>     placed in this bucket.
> - **Working Set:** An application that is not
>     currently in use but is run quite often, likely most days. For
>     example, even if for short periods, you’re likely to open the Twitter
>     app several times a day.
> - **Frequent:** An application that is not
>     currently in use but is sometimes opened throughout the week. For
>     example, if you go running 3 times a week then the app you use to
>     track your runs would fall into this.
> - **Rare:** An application that is
>     rarely used on the device. For example, a ride sharing app that you
>     may only use when you go on Holiday.
> - **Never:** An application that has
>     been installed but never launched.

**The overall impact can be described as follows:**

[image]